# Prevent javascript include in IE6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

I would love to hear your thoughts on this particular problem:

I'm using LinkedIn's button functionality and it comes likes this:

```
<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/profile" data-format="click" data-text="LinkedIn Profile"></script>
```

The only problem is that it renders very poorly in IE6, so all I want to do is to hide that button in IE6, I've thought about using the `<!--[if gte IE 7]>Javascript code here<![endif]-->` but that would also prevent it from loading in any other browser than IE, an other option would be to use the jquery: `if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version=="6.0"){ }` but how do I do that with SRC javascript files?

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you tried this:

```
<!--[if gte IE 7]>Javascript code here<![endif]-->
```

As you say, this will prevent non-IE browsers from seeing the script.

But there is a way of specifying conditional comments that will be ignored by other browsers. All you need to do is drop the hyphens that make it a comment, like this:

```
<![if gte IE 7]>Javascript code here<![endif]>
```

This will now work in all browsers, except IE prior to IE7.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment for more.

(by the way, off topic, and I'm sure you've heard this a million times already, but I would seriously recommend dropping support for IE6 -- there's virtually no-one still using it any more)

Comment: Thanks Spudley, works perfectly! I didn't know about this particular variation of the conditional comment possibility. (And I hear you about IE6.. but well, my company is using it for it's 1000 employees, and I don't have much of a choice...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!--[if ! lte IE 6]>Javascript code here<![endif]-->
```

or something like this

```
<!--[if (!IE)|(IE gt 6)]>Javascript code here<![endif]-->
```

Comment: very close, but this will also prevent it being included on non-IE browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(! IE6){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "src_to_js_file";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

or just use innerHTML to add the two script tags to DOM。

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `getScript` method

```
if(!($.browser.msie && $.browser.version=="6.0"))
    $.getScript('http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version=="6.0"){
  $('head').append('<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/profile" data-format="click" data-text="LinkedIn Profile"></script>')
}
```